# What are the details of Azure AD MFA?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, multi-factor-authentication

I am using Azure ADB2C for authentication.
And we've introduced MFA.
However, there is only one thing I don't understand.
That's the default value for MFA.
For example, the time it takes to get locked out or the lockout time.
Where can I find these details?
Please tell me!

Comment: In general, you can set the smart lockout values - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/threat-management

Comment: This is about login.I want to know about the MFA afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking about the tokens lifetime. You can setup under User Flows / Properties:

[image]

Also, from the official documentation:

> Access and ID token lifetimes (minutes) - The lifetime of the OAuth
> 2.0 bearer token and ID tokens. The default is 60 minutes (1 hour). The minimum (inclusive) is 5 minutes. The maximum (inclusive) is 1,440
> minutes (24 hours).
>
> Refresh token lifetime (days) - The maximum time
> period before which a refresh token can be used to acquire a new
> access token, if your application had been granted the offline_access
> scope. The default is 14 days. The minimum (inclusive) is one day. The
> maximum (inclusive) 90 days.
>
> Refresh token sliding window lifetime -
> The refresh token sliding window type. Bounded indicates that the
> refresh token can be extended as specify in the Lifetime length
> (days). No expiry indicates that the refresh token sliding window
> lifetime never expires.
>
> Lifetime length (days) - After this time
> period elapses the user is forced to reauthenticate, irrespective of
> the validity period of the most recent refresh token acquired by the
> application. The value must be greater than or equal to the Refresh
> token lifetime value.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-tokens?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Comment: thank you, your answer.
But,It may be a little different.
In the azure setting, I found something like this.
1:Number of MFA denials to trigger an account lockout
2:Minutes until account lockout counter is reset
3:Minutes until the account is automatically unblocked
I would like to know the default values for these.